# use a function inside a loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops, model

I am having problems in calling a function inside a for loop in R.

I have a function/model called X that has been defined already. And I want to use that function inside a for loop because I want to produce 50 results through that function/model

is it something like this?

```
func <- X(n)

   result = list()
   for (i in 1:50){
     result[i] = X(i)
    }
```

I was trying to look on some of the questions here but I don't seem to get it to work.
data)<-c("y",paste("X",1:p,sep=""))
X

I need to produce 50 datasets of X here.
X is a 100x10 matrix.

Comment: can you show `X`.  I would create a list like `result <- vector('list', 50)` and in the assignment `result[[i]] <- X(i)`

Comment: hey thanks! so here's the model. It's trying to produce 100x10 matrix.

Comment: The `result` is a `list`.  Each element will hold the output of that function applied

Comment: Can you please update your post by `edit`ing

Comment: Thank you for being so patient. edited.

Comment: edited the post above.

Comment: thank you! i didnt know i could use replicate nor i know that replicate existed. i was only using a for loop.

Comment: `replicate` is a great function for these kind of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that loops over columns instead of rows, in case that interests you.  I also did a "manual coding" of the replicate part.

```
gendata <- function(n, p) {
    y <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)
    y[y==0] <- -1
    
    X <- matrix(ncol=p, nrow=n)
    u <- runif(n)
    for(j in 1:p) {
        m <- rep(0, n)
        if(p %in% 1:3) m[u>0.3] <- p
        if(p %in% 4:6) m[u<0.3] <- p-3
        X[,j] <- rnorm(n, mean=m, sd=1)
    }
    
    data <- data.frame(cbind(y,X))
    names(data) <- c("y",paste("X",1:p,sep=""))
    
    return(data)
}

mylist <- vector(mode="list", length=50)
for (i in 1:50) {
    mylist[[i]] <- gendata(n=100, p=10)
}
```

Comment: thank you! it works too! this gives me more ways to understand how to attack a problem in R. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can wrap the code in a function and use `replicate`

```
f1 <- function(n, p) {
  y<-rbinom(n,1,0.5)
  y<-ifelse(y==0,-1,y)

   X<-matrix(ncol=p,nrow=n)
   for(i in 1:n){
     u<-runif(1)
    if(u>0.3){
     for(j in 1:3){
       X[i,j]<-y[i]*rnorm(1,j,1)
     }
    for(j in 4:6){
       X[i,j]<-y[i]*rnorm(1,0,1)
    }
    if(p>6){
      X[i,7:p]<-rnorm(p-6,0,1)
    }
    
  }else{
    for(j in 1:3){
      X[i,j]<-y[i]*rnorm(1,0,1)
    }
    for(j in 4:6){
      X[i,j]<-y[i]*rnorm(1,j-3,1)
    }
    if(p>6){
      X[i,7:p]<-rnorm(p-6,0,1)
    }
  }
}
data<-data.frame(cbind(y,X))
names(data)<-c("y",paste("X",1:p,sep=""))
data 
}
```

Now, we use `replicate`

```
out <- replicate(50, f1(n = 100, p = 10), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you! i'm still wrapping my head around the replicate command. This one is new to me! Thank you!